# Windows batch file to group 1000 files into alphanumeric folders

Tags: batch-file

This is my first post/request on here.  I've done numerous searches to try and find a solution, but I think my requirement is a tad ambitious.

I'm using Windows 7 and would prefer to do this in a <s>DOS</s> batch file rather than PowerShell.

I have folders containing 10s of thousands of old Zip archives.  Since there are so many files in one folder, it can be slow to list them.  I want to move the Zip archives into alphabetised folders, but each folder needs to be limited to 1000 files

So the first 1000 a*.zip files would be moved into a folder named A1. The second thousand a*.zip files into a folder named A2 and so on.

The files would need to be moved in order, so that if the last file copied into A1 is an_example_file_97.zip, then the first file moved into the A2 folder would be an_example_file_98.zip

I would need to do this for the whole alphabet and also numerically named Zip archives.  Then I would end up with a folder/file structure like this...

```
<DIR> 01
    1000 zip archives whose filename begins with a number
<DIR> 02
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with a number
<DIR> 03
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with a number

<DIR> A1
    1000 zip archives whose filename begins with A
<DIR> A2
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with A
<DIR> A3
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with A
<DIR> B1
    1000 zip archives whose filename begins with B
<DIR> B2
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with B
<DIR> B3
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with B

<DIR> Z1
    1000 zip archives whose filename begins with Z
<DIR> Z2
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with Z
<DIR> Z3
    Next 1000 zip archives whose filename begins with Z
```

My apologies if this solution already exists on this site, but it's tricky to know exactly what to search for.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm seriously hoping you'd at least want to use a Windows batch file, not a DOS one. But why the preference of batch file over PowerShell, if you have both at your disposal anyway? Just the amount of pain you want to endure? And the solution likely does not exist yet, as the problem fairly specific and unique.

Comment: @Joey, Windows batch file vs DOS batch file. I'm not aware of a functional difference.

Comment: @TroyTurley: DOS batch files are executed by `command.com` (and thus only work on 32-bit versions of Windows anyway) and are severely limited in what you can do, even more so than in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I agree with @Joey, `Windows 7` has `PowerShell` and a solution using it would likely be less painful.

Comment: @TroyTurley there are a lot of differences. For example DOS doesn't support `for /f`, `forfiles`... and other Windows-specific commands. It also doesn't have the `^` escape character, delayed expansion, extension, function or code blocks https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386

Comment: I learned something today. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far, it has been really useful.  With regards to PowerShell, I was only favouring Windows DOS because I'm more familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same [LotPings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50821663/778560), but with a couple small modifications that make it simpler and faster:

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

PushD "X:\start\here"
for %%A in (*.*) Do (
   Set "Name=%%~nA"
   Set "N=!Name:~0,1!"
   If "!N!" lss "a" Set "N=0"
   Set /A "Array[!N!]+=1, F=Array[!N!] / 1000 +1"
   Set "Dest=!N!!F!"
   If not Exist "!Dest!" REM MD "!Dest!"
   Echo Move "%%A" "!Dest!\"
)
```

If the listing of plain `for %%A` command is not sorted, then change the `for %%A in (*.*) Do (` line by these two lines:

```
for %%L in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) Do (
   for /F "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /ON %%L*') Do (
```

... and add a closing parentheses at end. This is better than a simple `for /F "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /ON *') Do (` because if the number of files is huge, then the execution of such a `for` could take *too much* time...

Comment: Nice enhancements +1. My answer was a quick shot in the middle of my birthday party as I didn't want to have powershell outpace batch without any resistance. I **do** like both scripting variants.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've been tinkering with this example, which almost seems to work perfectly, apart from when the files have those evil characters such as ! ' &, etc.   Is there a way to keep the filename intact so that these characters can remain?

Comment: Is there a way this script would work without using `EnableDelayedExpansion` ?  It's completely bypassing all files that have the exclamation mark in them, so they're not being moved into the relevant alpha directory.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell I'd probably approach it as follows (not really caring for efficiency for now):

1. Get list of files:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem |
   ```
2. Sort them by name (with numbers in the name sorted numerically instead of alphabetically)

   ```
   Sort-Object {
     [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { '{0:0000000000}' -f ([int]$args[0].Value) })
   }
   ```

   This will take care of sorting `some-name-100` after `some-name-99`.
3. Group by first character:

   ```
   Group-Object {
     $first = $_.Name[0];
     # Emit only a 0 for all numbers
     if ($first -match '[0-9]') { '0' } else { $first }
   } |
   ```
4. Take those groups and divide them into batches of at most 1000 elements

   ```
   ForEach-Object {
     $name = $_.Name
     $group = $_.Group
     0..([Math]::Floor($_.Count / 1000)) |
       ForEach-Object {
         $items = $group[($_ * 1000)..($_ * 1000 + 999)
         [pscustomobject] @{
           FirstLetter = $name
           Index = $_ + 1
           Items = $items
         }
       }
   } |
   ```
5. Create folders and move files to their respective folders

   ```
   ForEach-Object {
     $dir = New-Item Directory ($_.FirstLetter + $_.Index)
     $_.Items | Move-Item -Destination $dir
   }
   ```

This is untested, but should more or less work, probably. For testing you should perhaps test on dummy data and include a `-WhatIf` on the `Move-Item`.

All this is going to be much more painful in `cmd` than PowerShell, especially things like grouping, or sorting numerically.

Comment: IMHO [this `cmd` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824671/778560) is _much simpler_ than this PowerShell one...

Comment: Hi, thank you for this example.  Since I'm struggling to get the batch script to include files with an exclamation mark, I've opted to test the PowerShell version instead. On launching the script, it just generates a directory listing of all the contents of my test folder but doesn't create any folders and doesn't move any files.  What version of PowerShell should I be using please?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Joey I don't think it's to complicated or painful for batch.

Counting in an Array requires two level delayed expansion inside a for loop but that's it.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
PushD "X:\start\here"
for /F "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /ON *') Do (
  Set "Name=%%~nA"
  Set "N=!Name:~0,1!"
  Echo !N!|Findstr "[0-9]" 2>&1>NUL &&Set N=0
  Set /A "Array[!N!]+=1"
  Call Set "Count=%%Array[!N!]%%"
  Set /A "F=!Count! / 1000 +1, I = !Count! %% 1000"
  Set "Dest=!N!!F!"
  If not Exist "!Dest!" REM MD "!Dest!"
  Echo Move "%%A" "!Dest!\"
)
Set Array[
Pause
Popd
```

While testing the MD command is REMed out,
The Move command is only echoed.

Take a look at the counting Array[ variable finally output to see how much dirs would be created.

Shorted sample output:

```
Move "WSH_Shell_4.html" "W1\"
Move "xyz" "x1\"
Move "yarn.bat" "y1\"
Move "ZehnerZaehlen.cmd" "Z1\"
Move "zeiten.txt" "z1\"
Array[0]=7
Array[A]=10
Array[B]=3
Array[c]=30
Array[D]=19
Array[E]=15
Array[F]=18
Array[G]=29
Array[H]=11
Array[I]=9
Array[J]=2
Array[K]=1
Array[L]=9
Array[m]=20
Array[N]=5
Array[O]=4
Array[P]=11
Array[r]=16
Array[S]=25
Array[T]=17
Array[U]=19
Array[v]=3
Array[W]=19
Array[x]=1
Array[y]=1
Array[Z]=2
```

Comment: You may do the calculations in just one line this way: `Set /A "Array[!N!]+=1, F=Array[!N!] / 1000 +1"`. You are not using the `I` variable...

Comment: You are missing the grouping of names that start in digit into a folder that start in "0", but this point is very easy to fix; just add `if "!N!" lss "a" set "N=0"` before the `Set /A` command.

Comment: I would use a simpler `for %%A in (*.*) Do (` instead of your `for /F "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /ON *') Do (` that should run faster if the number of files is _huge_.

Comment: THat's true too, but you have no control over the sorting. Inherent sorting applies only to some file systems. (my NAS doesn't sort)

Comment: The question was vague about it, but considering the sample, I wouldn't assume the numbers in the files to be zero-padded, which is why I included numeric sort (which is actually the only really painful part I didn't want to do in batch files – well, and I haven't had practice in a while, considering that batch files are no longer needed to get something that runs on pretty much any Windows out there).

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "oldc1=*"
SET "oldsd=*"
SET "dircnt=4"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\*.zip" '
 ) DO (
 SET "c1=%%a"
 SET "c1=!c1:~0,1!"
 IF /i "!c1!" neq "!oldc1!" (
  REM we changed initial character
  SET "oldc1=!c1!"
  SET "destsd=!c1!"
  FOR %%b IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO IF "%%b"=="!c1!" SET "destsd=0"
  IF /i "!oldsd!" neq "!destsd!" (
   SET /a fcount=dircnt-1
   SET /a olddestsd2=9
   SET "oldsd=!destsd!"
  )
 )
 SET /a fcount +=1
 SET /a destsd2=fcount / dircnt
 IF !destsd2! neq !olddestsd2! (
  SET /a olddestsd2=destsd2
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\!destsd!!destsd2!" 2>nul
 )
 ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\!destsd!!destsd2!\"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Cut-and-paste the post to a .BAT file. Do not attempt to reformat for æsthetic reasons - batch can be quite sensitive to layout.

For testing, I set the value `dircnt` to 4. Your application requires 1000.

I'd suggest you use some dummy directories for testing.

This routine uses `delayed expansion` where `%var%` represents the value of a variable when a `code block` (parenthesised statement group) is parsed and `!var!` the value as it may change within the loop.

The first issue is to produce a directory-list in memory This listed is sorted in alphabetical order (`/on`) and of the basic format (`/b`) [names only] with no directorynames (`/a-d`). Each line of lines is then read by the `for` command and assigned to `%%a`.

`c1` is then employed to contain the first character of the filename which is compared with `oldc1` - the previous value so that the destination directoryname is only recalculated when the first character of the filename changes.

If the first character of the filename numeric, then the destination subdirectory will be `0?`, otherwise it's the first character of the filename now in `c1`. We initialise the filecount within this directory to the maximum - 1 and the subdirectory's second character to `9`.

This has established the new destination *if* the destination has changed.

We then increment the count of files moved and calculate the second character of the destination by simply dividing the count-of-files by the files-per-directory. Since batch does integer maths, the result is int(total files with this first character/files per directory), so it starts at `1`.

We then detect whether the destination directory has changed, and create the new directory if required.

Then move the file.

Comment: Thanks for this and for breaking it down to make it more understandable.

Comment: This script also does a great job, but it also fails to move files that have an exclamation mark anywhere in the filename. Would you happen to have a workaround for this please?